# Get time range from dates stored in DataRow of a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, timestamp, timespan, datarow

I need to get the length of the time between two timestamps. The data is in a datatable.

I was trying something like this.

```
System.TimeSpan date5 = (DateTime)drStatus["End"] - (DateTime)drStatus["Start"];
```

This does not error but just returns a decimal number. Can this be formatted hh:mm:ss?

Comment: Your second example gives you an error? What error does it give you? On what line?

Comment: Second example error Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'long' C:\ProjectsCorp\Accounting\AccountingTrackerReport\VS2010\Form1.cs 178 51 AccountingTrackerReport

Comment: `TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(end).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(start));`

Comment: If you look at the [constructors for DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) you will not find any constructor that takes just an object (drStatus["Start"] returns an object)

Comment: System.TimeSpan date5 = (DateTime)drStatus["End"] - (DateTime)drStatus["Start"]; returns a decimal.  Can this be formatted hh:mm:ss?

Comment: @MatthewD That does not return a `decimal` it returns a `TimeSpan` and you can format it with [`TimeSpan.ToString(string format)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Your first approach should return you a `TimeStamp` value.

Comment: @MatthewD a `TimeSpan` is not made up of month days and years.  It's made up of days, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds because years and months are not exact units of measure.

Comment: Of course, how do i apply that to date5?

Comment: Check out the [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx).  Or just use the default with `date5.ToString()`

Comment: @juharr Thank you for that timestring format .That get's me what i need too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default string representation of a `TimeSpan` is `[-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff]` when using [`TimeSpan.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can specify your own [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx) with [`TimeSpan.ToString(string format)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx), but it should be noted that the hour formatter will not include hours that are included in the day portion.  If you want a `hh:mm:ss` format where the hours can go over 24 then you need

```
string result = string.Format(
    "{0}:{1:00}:{2:00}", 
    myTimeSpan.Days * 24 + myTimeSpan.Hours, 
    Math.Abs(myTimeSpan.Minutes), 
    Math.Abs(myTimeSpan.Seconds));
```

The `Math.Abs` is needed to avoid something like "-12:-30:-20" when the `TimeSpan` is negative.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite simple way to do it here

```
var startTime1 = DateTime.Now.ToString();
var endTime1 = DateTime.Now.ToString();
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endTime1).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime1));
var formattedTimeSpan = duration.ToString(@"hh\ \:\ mm\ \:\ ss\ \:\ fff");
```

Comment: Sure, but what is `endTime` and `startTime`?  It's obvious that the OP's original error was subtracting the same column value from itself.

Comment: What issue do you see with OP's first approach `System.TimeSpan date5 = (DateTime)drStatus["End"] - (DateTime)drStatus["Start"];`?

Comment: You mean the variables that he says produce an error because he's using the `DateTime` ctor incorrectly?

Comment: @Rahul are you saying that there is not more than one way to skin a cat.. ? this is is very straight forward so not sure what your point is..

Comment: I think his point is that you're just giving a different approach when the original problems where subtracting the same value from itself and using a ctor incorrectly.  Now the problem seems to be formatting a `TimeSpan`.  Your answer currently doesn't address any of those problems.

Comment: the problem is not formatting he stated can it be.. so we won't know if it's a problem until he actually understands and or tries to use the `TimeSpan.ToString("hh;mm;ss")`

Comment: @  MethodMan i am trying that but how do i apply that to date5?